Raspberry Pi Zero. Not booting anymore
My Pi Zero has been up and running continuously for 6 months (with an occasional reset). It's running a homebrew home automation app.
Suddenly it  has stopped working, without any help from me!
Now it crashes about 7 seconds into the boot.
I have posted a photo of the output that is generated.
I have mounted the SD card in Ubuntu laptop and fsck'd the rootfs and bootfs. All looks good but the same Pi boot issue still pertains.
Any ideas? Is my Pi Zero bricked? Is it worth trying another SD card? Are there any other boot logs that might shed some light?
Many thanks

You need to fsck that SDCard. It may have gone read-only (which is what SDCards do when they're end-of-life). To fsck that SDCard on your Raspberry you'll need a USB SDcard reader and a second SDCard (to boot from). You can do it with any Linux system (like a Linux laptop with a USB SDCard reader) - if you don't have a spare SDCard.

Hi Dougie. Thanks. Yes I have already removed the SD card and fsck'd it on a separate laptop. It fsck'd OK.

I have now noticed that the rootfs "sys" folder is completely empty. This cannot be correct surely?

/sys is a virtual folder ... the files inside exist only in ram when the kernel is running ... the SD card will not contain any files there

Is it worth trying another SD card? - yes

@jsotola - thanks. Has saved me much work. New SD card is on its way
